# What would the James Webb telescope see if it looked at itself from Earth?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, visibility-of-spacecraft

[This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/can-any-other-telescopes-see-the-james-webb-space-telescope) asks whether any ground-based telescopes can see the James Webb. The answer ("*yes, but it's basically just an indistinct dot*") is deeply underwhelming. If only we had a *much better* telescope that we could use to look at it...

***What would the James Webb see if it imaged itself from Earth Orbit?***

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 4):

The answer is going to be deeply underwhelming *regardless* of what telescope you use, because of the sunshield, and because of its location.

It lives at the [Earth-Sun L2 point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point), as shown on this handy diagram from wikipedia:

[image: Diagram of the Earth-Sun lagrange points]

this means we will always be on the sunward-side of the device, which means all we will ever be able to see is the sun-side of the sun-shield. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope#Features) has this image:

[image: Rendering of the underside of the JWST]

That's a visible-light rendering, of course, and I'm not entirely sure what it would look like in the IR spectra that the JWST sees in. [NIRCam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIRCam) can see 600nm light (orangey). I can't see what angular resolution it has for visible-light imaging, but for near IR at 2000nm it is [0.07 seconds of arc](https://www.as.arizona.edu/nircam). The face of the sunshield will be at a nice warm [383K](https://jwst.nasa.gov/content/observatory/sunshield.html) so it'll be visible to at least one of the JWST's sensors, I'm sure.

The L2 point is ~1.5 million km away from Earth, and at that distance 0.07 arc seconds is equivalent to a feature size of a little over 500m. Given that the JWST is 20m long in its largest dimension, you're not actually going to get a blurry image... you're going to get a single pixel. Technically, it might be quite sharp. Just not very interesting.