# Can the JWST look at Earth? What would it see?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, lagrangian-points, earth-observation, resolution

There's a few questions on the site about whether we can see the James Webb Space Telescope from Earth (i.e. [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/can-any-other-telescopes-see-the-james-webb-space-telescope) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58057/what-would-the-james-webb-telescope-see-if-it-looked-at-itself-from-earth/58058)), but I'm wondering about the opposite - can we see Earth using the JWST?

I realize that its position at L2 means that we'd be pointing it straight at the sun and a comment on one of the linked questions says that we'd probably damage the scope in doing so. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point#L2:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20the%20angular%20radius%20of%20the%20sun%20as%20viewed%20from%20L2%20is%20arcsin(695.5%C3%97103/151.1%C3%97106)%C2%A0%E2%89%88%C2%A00.264%C2%B0%2C%20whereas%20that%20of%20the%20earth%20is%20arcsin(6371/1.5%C3%97106)%C2%A0%E2%89%88%C2%A00.242%C2%B0.%20Looking%20toward%20the%20sun%20from%20L2%20one%20sees%20an%20annular%20eclipse.) that the Earth and the Sun would be almost exactly the same size when viewed from L2 (0.242° and 0.264°, respectively, resulting in an annular eclipse).

If it didn't damage the scope, the [reported 0.1 arc-second resolution](https://www.jwst.nasa.gov/content/about/faqs/faq.html#sharp) (0.00003°) seems like it might be able to distinguish some features on Earth. This would also be in the infrared, of course, but infrared pictures of Earth are still neat - unless they're completely washed out by the ring of sunlight?

Comment: Arrgh, found more info immediately after posting this that I couldn't find before: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57492/can-james-webb-take-pictures-of-our-solar-system-in-what-ways-will-they-differ and its link to NASA: https://webb.nasa.gov/content/forScientists/faqSolarsystem.html#whatlookat. Flagged for closing as duplicate.

Comment: You as the question author have the right to delete your question, you don't need to flag for closing.